# Swap draggable items from separated div`s in the same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to make a nice example for Draggable jQuery with Bootstrap, it's working fine till now but what I need to make is:

1. Swap the `div`s `<div class='col-sm-12'></div>` that I created between the `div.cart` with same place.
2. Can add 1 item only in one `div.cart`.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $("#catalog div").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
  });

  $(".cart ").droppable({
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".RemoveDIV").remove();
        $("<div class='col-sm-4'></div>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);

      }
    })
    .sortable({
      connectWith: ".cart"
    }).sortable({
      items: " > div"
    });
});
```

```css
#products {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: 2em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#cart {
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="height:220px;background-color:gray;">
  <div id="catalog">
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 color">Test1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 color1">Test2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 color">Test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bigContainer">
  <div class="container" style=" margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="cart col-sm-6" style="height:250px;background-color:#043F35;">
      <div class="RemoveDIV">Add your items here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart col-sm-6" style="height:250px;background-color:#BC0F76;">
      <div class="RemoveDIV">Add your items here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could achieve your goal editing `accept` property of droppable in this way

```
accept: function(draggable) {
        return $(this).find(".col-sm-4").length == 0;
}
```

in this way the function will allow the draggable elements only if there is no element with class `col-sm-4` inside it

Comment: Thanks @faby , but its not working : can you make it in the JSFiddle ?

Comment: check in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vg2mnr6e/1/. In this way you can add only one item from the catalog div. Is what you need?

Comment: Thanks faby again but what about the main issue ? i need to swap the droppable with same place

Comment: Can you give me an example? you want to revert the items from .cart to catalog?

Comment: nope , i have now 2 div`s of .cart . i need to swap the item from the the first .cart to the second .cart with the same place in the div ! i hope you understand me , you my only hope :(

Comment: we can solve it! So you want that when someone drop one item to first chart automatically should be copyed to the second cart? I'm sorry if I don't understand your main problem but my English isn't so good

Comment: no problem , i will explain it . i have 2 carts
<div class="cart">item1</div> <div class="cart">item2</div>
when i drag item1 to the second cart the items are swap
then be <div class="cart">item2</div> <div class="cart">item1</div>